# Rotate exit survey pop ups on order success page on magento

Tags: php, magento, survey

I have two exit surveys on my magento order success page. One is Resellerrating exit survey and another is from PriceGrabber.

I dont want to overload customers with both pop ups on order success, I would like to rotate the scripts so that on one order shows up only one of those exit survey pop ups and on another order shows up another exit survey, those pop ups are implemented via javascript inserted in my success.phtml so I guess I will need to include those both script snippets in some kind of php code but I dont know what code and how : ))

Even more ideal solution would be, if the pricegrabber review pop up showed up ONLY for customers who visited my website from pricegrabber, but I dont know if thats something easy to implement.

I hope any of you gurus here can help me out with this : ))

Thank you,
Jon

Comment: If you don't post what you've already tried people are much less likely to help you.  StackOverflow works best when you need a programming question answered, not when you're too cheap to keep a developer on retainer and hope the internet will solve all your problems for you.

Comment: Calling a person cheap when you have no idea about specific situation doesn't show much about your professional ethics, does it? 

As for the specifics, I have 2 code snippets on success.phtml, both of them are exit survey pop ups, 1 from Resellerratings, 2nd from pricegrabber, both code snippets are in the footer of the success.phtml, so I need a some kind of php or any kind of code that will make this code snippets active in turns. So that they will pop up on Successful orders in turns and never together.

Answer (score 0):

To switch between both codes you would put both codes in javascript on the success.phtml

```
function isEven(Ordernumber) 
{
   //Resellerrating Exit Survey
}

function isOdd(Ordernumber)
{
   //PriceGrabber Exit Survey
}
```

that would switch between the 2.

to show the PG survey for customers who visited your website from pricegrabber. You can 
1) a parameter to all the URL's you submit to Pricegrabber identifying the customer as coming from pricegrabber 
2) use  $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] and check if it is pricegrabber

Then you can set a new session variable to ref=pricegrabber

this will allow you identify that the customer came from PG

then you can do a JS script on you success.phtml. if the session variable ref=pricegrabber then show the pricegrabber code otherwise show the Resellerrating code